# -bash: command not found in macOS 12.6.3. How can I fix this?

Tags: bash, zsh

I am a new to macOS and I am using an the iMac running macOS 12.6.3 (Monterey)  I am trying to load pygame.

I have already loaded python 3.11 and pycharm. Every time I try to load pygame I keep getting the error that it can not load because of a file problem not associated with PIP.

Most solutions require Homebrew but to load it I have to use Bash.   When I do I get command not found. I can not load Homebrew or any program requiring Bash.

After much searching, I believe the problem is I have lost Bash or Zsh somehow. I do not know where to go to find them. Every command I have found to locate bash uses Bash and returns command not found.

Can you tell me how to find the file without using Bash? Or how can I reload bash and where should I put it?

Señor CMasMas's comment below allowed me to start installing
Homebrew, it is installing now.

Before I started the Homebrew install I tried to close the terminal and as soon as I got out of terminal, the path reverted to what it was before. I typed in the suggested code again and then started Homebrew.

How can I make the changes to the path permanent? I tried searching for the .rc file but nothing was found.

Comment: Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29688932/mac-terminal-bash-command-not-found) from StackOverflow and check back if it doesn't help you.  You might also read [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/what-is-the-unix-path-and-how-do-you-add-programs-to-it/) to make it make sense.  I myself have never seen this on my mac but of course it is possible since it follows the rules that almost all OSs do.

Comment: bash and zsh are extremely hard to remove in recent versions of macOS, since they're in the areas protected by System Integrity Protection (SIP). It's much more likely your `PATH` variable is messed up, and as a result they system doesn't know where to look for them (and other command files). There are a lot of earlier questions about problems like this, and I recommend looking through them to see if any are relevant to your situation.

Comment: Senor CMasMas -  Thank you.   this allowed me to start installing homebrew.   It is installing now.  But before I started the homebrew install I tried to close the terminal and as soon as I got out of terminal the path reverts to what it was before.   I typed in your code again and then started homebrew.       How can I make the changes to the path permanent.   I tried searching for the .rc file but nothing was found.

Comment: When someone asks for clarifications or gives suggestions in commentary, instead of answering in comments it's better to [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1767234/edit) the question to add new info, as I now did for you. This way everything relevant is readily available for community members and the question reflects the current situation.

Comment: It sounds like something in one of your shell initialization files is messing up the `PATH` variable for each new shell as it starts up. Run `/bin/ls -A ~` to list files in your home directory (including normally-invisible ones that start with "."), and look for files like `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, `.zprofile`, `.zshrc`, `.zshenv`, etc. You'll have to examine the contents of those for lines that have assignments to `PATH`.